# Oracle Percentage Calculation with two decimal digit rounded off

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following query

```
SELECT 
STUDENT_NAME, 
TOTAL, 
GRAND_TOTAL, 
(CASE WHEN GRAND_TOTAL <> 0 THEN TOTAL / GRAND_TOTAL * 100 END) AS PERCENTAGE 
FROM VW_ALL_STUDY_DETAILS;
```

Which returns

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STUDENT_NAME | TOTAL   | GRAND_TOTAL      | PERCENTAGE                          
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    RahulS    |    2    |        7         |  28.57142857142857142857142857142857142857   
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    KiranK    |    15   |        14        | 93.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now my question is how do I round to only 1 decimal place? (i.e. 28.5% & 93.3%)

Thanks Inadvance!

Comment: Hint: Trunc or Round function.

Answer (score 0):

see [round](https://habr.com/ru/post/122445/) function

```
SELECT 
STUDENT_NAME, 
TOTAL, 
GRAND_TOTAL, 
ROUND((CASE WHEN GRAND_TOTAL <> 0 THEN TOTAL / GRAND_TOTAL * 100 END),1) AS PERCENTAGE 
FROM VW_ALL_STUDY_DETAILS;
```